# Date between fdate and tdate based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server, please tell me how to solve

Table: `Patient`

```
                         (MM-dd-yy)     (MM-dd-yy) (MM-dd-yy)
pn |    rvs     |prcode |date   |amount |datefdate| datetdate|  entry
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |07-23-14|  07-23-14|   b
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |08-04-14|  08-04-14|   b
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |08-11-14|  08-11-14|   b
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |08-20-14|  08-20-14|   b
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |08-26-14|  08-26-14|   b
61 |    NULL    |MS001  |NULL   |NULL   |09-03-14|  09-03-14|   b
61 |            |00000  |       |       |01-01-80|  10-06-14|   b
61 |            |00000  |       |       |01-01-80|  10-06-14|   b
61 |            |MS001  |       |        |01-06-15|  01-06-15|   b
61 |    97124   |MS001  |01-06-15|120.00|NULL    |    NULL   |  c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |07-23-14|120.00|NULL    |    NULL    |  c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |08-04-14|120   |    |                |  c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |08-11-14|120   |    |                |  c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |08-20-14|120   |    |                |  c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |08-26-14|120   |    |                |c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |09-03-14|120   |   |                  | c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |09-15-14|75    |   |                  | c
61 |    97124   |MS001  |09-15-14|0 |   |                      |c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |10-27-14|75    |   |                  | c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |11-04-14|75    |   |            |       c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |11-10-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |11-25-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |12-02-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |12-09-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |12-15-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |12-22-14|75    |   |            |        c
61 |    60MIN   |MS001  |12-30-14|75    |   |            |       c
```

Here I want to compare entry type= c records date data between datefdate and datetdate with entry type b records

If this condition is met, then output we retrieve entry type =c records related data and one new column is added to identify records

Status records in new column if condition not satisfy then we retrieve entry type=c records related data and new columns status is "unbilled"

Finally every time we need to compare entry type=c records date is between datefdate and datetdate with entry type B records.

If condition is met, then that records billed, otherwise unbilled.

I tried like below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT [a].[pn],
                a.rvs,
                a.date,
                a.prcode,
                a.amount,
                b.datefdate,
                b.datetdate,
                CASE
                  WHEN ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(a.date AS DATE), 120) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.datefdate)) AS DATE), 120) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.datetdate)) AS DATE), 120) ) THEN 'billed'
                  WHEN ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(a.date AS DATE), 120) NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.datefdate)) AS DATE), 120) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.datetdate)) AS DATE), 120) ) THEN 'unbilled'
                END AS [Filter]
FROM   testbilled a
       JOIN testbilled b
         ON a.pn = '61'
WHERE  a.entry = 'c'
       AND b.entry = 'b'
```

its not give correct result. it is multiplay9*18=144 records commening.

i want output like below:

```
pn  rvs date    bcharge entry   prcode  filter
61  60MIN   09-15-14         75.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  60MIN   10-27-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   11-04-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   11-10-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   11-25-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   12-02-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   12-09-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   12-15-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   12-22-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  60MIN   12-30-14         75.00  C   MS001   UnBilled
61  97124   01-06-15        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   07-23-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   08-04-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   08-11-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   08-20-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   08-26-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   09-03-14        120.00  C   MS001   Billed
61  97124   09-15-14          0.00  C   MS001   Billed
```

Please tell me how to achieve this issue in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Subquery? if not then check this :

```
SELECT pn,
       rvs,
       date,
       amount,
       entry,
       prcode,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM   @YourTable b
                     WHERE  a.date BETWEEN b.datefdate AND b.datetdate
                            AND b.entry = 'b'
                            AND a.pn = b.pn) THEN 'BILLED'   ELSE 'UNBILLED'
       END [Filter]
FROM   @YourTable a
WHERE  a.entry = 'c'
ORDER  BY amount
```

Comment: Hi thanks almost we got good but without patientnumber compare we cannot do becasue of in table have multiple pn that time above query not works.

Comment: add it in where clause of subquery `AND a.pn = b.pn` ??